# Wiring a Key Switch to Control USB Power?

Tags: power, usb, safety, cables

So I'm working on a project, and I'm a bit stumped on this problem I ran into. Brief explanation, I have wired a key switch into the power pin of a USB extension cable, which will allow the female end to be toggled on/off depending on the key position.

[image: keyswitch]

My problem is that this specific switch has a .7 ohm resistance. My initial solution was to solder a button cell battery to the cable to provide the extra volts. My question is whether or not supplying more than the 5 volts expected from the USB port will damage either the port or the device on the receiving end (I'm using a USB drive, and the .7 ohms prevents readability of the drive).

Comment: Can you show a schematic? There are at least two ways to connect a button cell. I want to make sure I understand which way you did it. It is definitely a terrible idea no matter what, but I would prefer to see the schematic before I reply.

Comment: No, do not do that.  You are mixing things up pretty severely, for example confusing resistance and voltage.  At the maximum conventional USB current of 500 ma, a 0.7 ohm resistor would create a drop of only 350 mv.  Also, your coin cell probably can't begin to supply that much current.   Back up and focus on the actual problem, not coin cells and chewing gum as an attempt at solution.

Comment: 0.7 Ohms prevents your drive from working? I'm thinking you've missed something. At 500mA that's only 0.35V drop.

Comment: You shouldn't be running a USB drive on an  extension cable *at all*.

Comment: If you can't get a better key switch, you could use a relay or transistor with a lower on resistance.

Comment: This is obviously some kind of XY problem. I'm therefore voting to close.

Comment: @dim: It's not obviously and XY problem to me. What's an XY problem?

Comment: @transistor It's a case where the OP asks for a question that is not his actual original problem, but something he thinks will solve his original problem (but which most certainly won't). Mmh, my explanation is sloppy: [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Does the USB drive work on the cut-open extension cable if you simply bypass the switch? Nonstandard cables can and do work, but only over short distances. Also, you've disconnected the shield which might matter.

Comment: @immibis - a transistor would be *even worse* than a mechanical switch.  A MOSFET as suggested by SamGibson below might work, but the whole idea of inline power switching for a USB disk driver is dubious.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Could you explain why a transistor is a poor choice compared to a MOSFET?

Comment: Alternative, far more reliable solution: a small powered hub with its own supply. Wire the keyswitch to the hub power supply.

Comment: @pjc50 - Good suggestion (+1). Unfortunately for those people (which may not include the OP) who are using USB-powered external hard drives connected to laptops, away from mains power sources, adding a mains-powered hub may not be an option. However for others, your suggestion might be a possible solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A MOSFET is a kind of transistor...

Comment: @immibis only when you specifically designate a MOSFET.  If you just recommend "a transistor" someone will reach for a standard bipolar, and that will turn out worse than the mechanical switch.  A recommendation that leaves the hard part unsaid for the reader to just know, while appearing on the surface to mean something that will not work, is not a useful contribution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Could you then Explain how a transistor used as a Switching element with tens to a single hundred of milivolts of saturation would be worse than 0.7Ohms? With about 3 seconds of clicking, for example, something like this one: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NSS60601MZ4-D.PDF - And that's not even a particularly good one.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are supplying power down the USB cable to your drive, I am assuming yours is a 2.5" external hard disk drive, which *only* gets its power via USB (sometimes called "portable" USB hard drives).

> I'm using a USB drive, and the .7 ohms prevents readability of the drive

Yes, that result can easily happen, depending on the specific external hard drive, the current-supply capabilities of the specific PC/laptop USB port, and the specific USB cables used. Or to put it another way - some people have problems, some don't, due to different components being used.

Some USB-powered hard drives are *very* sensitive to any voltage drop, and can fail to operate when other (lower power) equipment works OK. At power-on, a typical 2.5" hard disk drive which is not designed for low-current power-on, exceeds the maximum current from a single USB 2.x port by a significant amount (e.g. briefly requiring >1 A during power-on vs. the 500 mA maximum from a USB 2.x port, and even that doesn't have to be available without USB enumeration, though it usually is).

These drives only power-on at all due to capacitors, luck, and USB ports supplying more current than the USB specification requires - or Y-cables!

Some other 2.5" drives can be configured for a low-current power-on, where the drive limits its current required to around 500 mA during spin-up, at the cost of having a longer spin-up phase. However those drives still have limits for acceptable voltage drop and hence limits for any significant resistance in the power cables.

> My initial solution was to solder a button cell battery to the cable to provide the extra volts.

This won't work. Such cells cannot supply the necessary current.

> My problem is that this specific switch has a .7 ohm resistance.

That is only *part* of your problem. In addition to the resistance of the switch:

- You have also added extra resistance by using a USB extension cable. We can't see how long it is in the photo, but its power wires look thin, so it isn't one of the cables with specially thicker power wires. That additional cable will increase the voltage drop measured at the drive itself.
- You have removed the shielding from (what looks like) 4"-6" of the USB data pair in the cable. That could increase data-related problems caused by external interference. It is good that you *didn't* untwist the wires in the USB data pair; that would have been even worse.
- It also appears that you have broken the end-to-end continuity of the cable's shielding. Again, that will not help reliable USB data communications.
- Switching-off power to USB-powered hard drives should not be done lightly. If the disk is spinning when the power is switched-off, it forces an "emergency retract" which is a high-stress mechanical event for the drive and can cause data corruption to any writes-in-progress, and loss of any pending writes.

If you insist on having a power switch like this, then use one of the previous suggestions e.g. a switch-operated carefully-chosen relay or MOSFET (selected to minimise the added resistance), a very short USB extension cable preferably with thicker power wires e.g. 20AWG, removing the minimum of USB shielding, and perhaps it *might* work. But since success depends on the specific requirements of that USB-powered hard drive and the PC's USB port, there is no guarantee that the overall configuration can cope with any additional resistance at all.

Of course for normal low USB power situations, a Y-cable might be suggested. However if you are trying to *switch* the power, then these cables add to the complexity, as you then need to switch the power coming from two USB ports instead of one!

Comment: Not to forget about not even coming close to fiddling with the coupling distance and twist of the data-pair if you want to get to anything faster than the very first draft proposal of USB1.0